# Canvas framerate drop

Tags: java, android, multithreading, canvas

I have an activity called MainActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Customview cust_view;
CustomThread cust_thread;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    cust_view=new Customview(this);

    setContentView(cust_view);

    cust_thread= new CustomThread();

    cust_thread.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

    }
```

I have defined a custom view named Customview by extending the view.Inside the onDraw method,i draw a circle ...change it,s x co-ordinate..call invalidate.Thus my circle bounces from one edge of screen to other.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class Customview extends View
{
Paint paint = new Paint();
float circle_x;
int mul=1;
public Customview(Context context) {
    super(context); 
}


public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{   
    circle_x+=2*mul;

    if(circle_x==canvas.getWidth())
        mul=mul*-1;
    if(circle_x==0)
        mul=mul*-1;

    canvas.drawCircle(circle_x, 100, 400, paint);
invalidate();
}

}
```

I also have a custom thread named CustomThread made by extending thread.Inside the run() is an EMPTY while loop which keeps looping.

```
public class CustomThread extends Thread{


@Override
public void run() { 

while(true)
   {

    }

                }
}
```

Now if i start the thread in my main activity, there is a frame drop during the movement of the circle...it is like..move move move..slight pause for a moment..then move again.. and this repeats.

If i DONT start the thread,it moves smoothly.

And something strange too:

If i start the thread but this time,if i put

```
Thread.sleep(0);
```

in my run() method,  it is smooth again.

What is going on?

How can i fix it?

Comment: what is that Thread for?

Comment: nothing yet.just a test

Comment: if your Thread is not interrupted by any blocking operation it eats cpu and you see that everything slows down

Comment: Then why is the lag almost periodical with a period of almost 4 seconds?

Comment: This is an tricky question.
My best guess (based on the fact that when you put your thread to sleep the drawing runs smoothly) is that the thread is wasting a lot of cpu cycles, and sometimes it's so intensive that the drawing of the view hangs.

Comment: But the argument of sleep is 0

Answer (score 0):

Using "invalidate();" in onDraw() isn't a good idea for your device, you should replace by postInvalidateDelayed(20);